# How to remove empty strings from a MATLAB array of structs

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, struct, matlab-struct

I have a MATLAB array of structs with a field called `image_name`. There are a few entries where

```
x(n).image_name = []
```

(i.e., the nth row of the struct array has an `image_name` that's empty)

I would like to remove them by trying something along the lines of

```
idx = [x.image_name] == []
x(idx) = [];
```

but can't get the indices of the empty strings. Every variation I try generates an error.

How can I find the row indices of the empty strings, so I can remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{}` to convert the names to a cell array and then use `isempty` (within `cellfun`) to find the empty entries and remove them.

```
ismt = cellfun(@isempty,  {x.image_name});
x = x(~ismt);
```

Or in one line

```
x = x(~cellfun(@isempty, {x.image_name}));
```

**Update**

As mentioned by [@Rody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987099/how-to-remove-empty-strings-from-a-matlab-array-of-structs/36987132?noredirect=1#comment61529163_36987132) in the comments, using `'isempty'` rather than constructing an anonymous function is significantly faster.

```
x = x(~cellfun('isempty', {x.image_name}));
```

Comment: +1. Just for completeness: using the string argument to `cellfun` used to be a lot faster than using anonymous functions (i.e., `cellfun('isempty', {x.image_name})`). Not sure if this is still true in recent MATLAB...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Oh wow, just tested it and it looks like it's still true. I never realized that, thanks!

Comment: Good to know it still works :) Be sure to check out the other possible string arguments; old-fashioned, but pretty darned useful for larger cell arrays.

Comment: This is interesting. I thought that difference between `@isempty` and `'isempty'` would have disappeared in recent versions. Which version did you test on, @Suever?

Comment: @LuisMendo Tested on R2015b (new execution engine). Used the following script: `a = {'a', ''}; b = a(randi(1:2,1000,1)); disp(timeit(@()cellfun(@isempty, b))); disp(timeit(@()cellfun('isempty', b)));`

Comment: @Suever Thanks. I also get faster results (about 70 times) with R2015b on Windows 7